# sidekiq report exception Celluloid::Task::TerminatedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq for my rails production queue management. recently, I start receiving Celluloid::Task::TerminatedError exception. I have no clue where this error comes from

here comes some information:

Sidekiq version: sidekiq (3.3.0)

The error message:

```
Stacktrace (most recent call first):

celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:34:in `terminate'
super
celluloid/actor.rb:345:in `each'
tasks.to_a.each(&:terminate)
celluloid/actor.rb:345:in `cleanup'
tasks.to_a.each(&:terminate)
celluloid/actor.rb:329:in `shutdown'
cleanup exit_event
celluloid/actor.rb:164:in `run'
shutdown
celluloid/actor.rb:130:in `block in start'
run
celluloid/thread_handle.rb:13:in `block in initialize'
yield
celluloid/actor_system.rb:32:in `block in get_thread'
yield
celluloid/internal_pool.rb:130:in `call'
proc.call
celluloid/internal_pool.rb:130:in `block in create'
proc.call
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is your redis server running?

Comment: yes, it is running but with a connection limt to 5, is it possible that the connection limit is reached? @raskhadafi